# call the default home screen from application

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers

I need to call the default home screen that comes with my phone from my application which is also a home screen app. I've tried searching and find this

```
    ArrayList<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent intent=null;
    final PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
    for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo:packageManager.queryIntentActivities(new 
                  Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), 
                                                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
    intent=packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                          resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
    intentList.add(intent);
    }
```

this code is working for the all the other launchers but not for the default launcher. I tried using break points in code and found that at 0 index of list there should be default launcher intent but intent does'nt hold the value. Do I need some kind of permission
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just simple get the name and class from ResolveInfo and make intent manualy like for sonyercisson the package name is "com.sonyericsson.home" and class is "com.sonyericsson.home.HomeActivity"

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClassName("com.sonyericsson.home", "com.sonyericsson.home.HomeActivity");
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   startActivity(intent);
```

it works

Answer (score 7):

Hope this will do.

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: that works for the home screen set as default but I want to open the home screen that comes with my mobile even if its not set as default