# Transparent activity on Resume doesn't show up android

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I have 3 activities:
Home(Base activity) with

```
 <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="com.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Other two activites:
Activity1 and Activity2

with theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`
can be called from each other or from home.

They always return to home onBackpress()
it is override

```
intent.setClass(this, Home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

when activity1 is called from activity2

```
intent.setClass(this, ACtivity2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

its onResume is called but cannot be seen
Is there any solution?

**I want only single instance of Activity in stack.**

**Requirements:**
Activity1 and Activity2 should once created should never be destroyed(They should be always called from history) until Home is called.

Help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

[Visited this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309479/bug-theme-translucent-flag-activity-reorder-to-front)

Comment: There is a long-standing bug in Android regarding a combination of FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and translucent theme. It does not work as it should. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309479/bug-theme-translucent-flag-activity-reorder-to-front

Answer (score 2):

I assume the problem occurs because you are using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for Home Activity.

As, It performs

> If there is already an instance of the called activity type present in
>   the stack, then this instance is brought to the foreground instead of
>   creating a new instance. Also, all activities in the stack that reside
>   on top of that instance are cleared from the stack. For example,
>   assuming that the current activity stack is ABCDE, launching an
>   activity of type C will clear activities D and E from the task and
>   result in the stack ABC.

So your Activity 1 and Activity 2 gets cleared when you call Home Activity.

Solution :

Call Home Activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED or FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

AS, It performs

> This flag has no effect unless the intent creates a new task or brings
>   an existing task to the foreground. In that case, the task is reset,
>   meaning that task affinities are applied (resulting in activities
>   being moved from or to this task) and that, given that
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET is set as well, the task is
>   cleared according that flag’s specification.

Comment: I want HOME to be always base activity not to bring it to front, as from HOME only you can leave application.

Comment: In Home Activity, write onBackPressed Event, and call Phone's Home Screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515990/call-the-default-home-screen-from-application @hanry

Comment: If there is custom launcher installed (GoLauncher) it will always ask for home to be selected  on back pressed if default launcher is not selected

Comment: Try with `exit(0)` instead calling home screen intent, I have not checked.. so test it if it works for your issue @hanry

Comment: You may use this code to go to the default launcher screen directly : http://pastebin.com/Fz6rLkwy @hanry

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest give

```
android:launchMode="singleinstance";
```